# how can i conditionally filter an array

Tags: swift

Im trying to filter an array of objects by property values

```
      queryDatasource = datasource.filter {
            if (!values.users.isEmpty && values.users.contains($0.User.User)) {
                return true
            }

            if (!values.categories.isEmpty && values.categories.contains($0.Category.Category)) {
                return true
            }

            if (!values.priorities.isEmpty && values.priorities.contains($0.Priority.Priority)) {
                return true
            }

            if (!values.statuses.isEmpty && values.statuses.contains($0.Status.Status)) {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
```

When i select only a user `Sara`, it works as expected, i only see results from `Sara`.
When i select a second user `Mike`, it still work as expected, only results by `Mike` and `Sara`.

Now, if i added a priority filter `High`, it returns all objects by `Mike` and `Sara` AND all objects with the priority `High` ignoring the users (i get a high priority object by the user `Dave`  which is unintended)

In a nutshell, i want to filter by `User` AND `Priority` AND `Category` OR `Status`. if its in the users filter, it has to match

Comment: You don't need to check if a collection is not empty before chaining contains. Contains will just return false.

Comment: I find the title of this question very confusing.

Comment: You are overlapping the results. When it checks by priority it ignores the results of the above if clauses and return just the results of the current if clause.

Comment: @sara Swift convention is to reserve UpperCamelCase for types, and to use lowerCamelCase for properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll arrive at the solution step-by-step, to show you how I got there.

Firstly, remove all the unnecessary `!values.x.isEmpty` checks. If a sequence is empty, `contains(_:)` will just always return false, so we don't need to worry about it. Also, I'd remove all of the unnecessary bracketing from the predicate:

```
queryDatasource = datasource.filter {
    if values.users.contains($0.User.User) {
        return true
    }

    if values.categories.contains($0.Category.Category) {
        return true
    }

    if values.priorities.contains($0.Priority.Priority) {
        return true
    }

    if values.statuses.contains($0.Status.Status) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

From here, we're in a better position to identify this as an `or` operation, so let's explicitly rewrite it as such:

```
queryDatasource = datasource.filter {
    return values.users.contains($0.User.User)
    || values.categories.contains($0.Category.Category)
    || values.priorities.contains($0.Priority.Priority)
    || values.statuses.contains($0.Status.Status)
}
```

And if we can use `or` (`||`), clearly we can just switch to `and` (`&&`):

```
queryDatasource = datasource.filter {
    return values.users.contains($0.User.User)
    && values.categories.contains($0.Category.Category)
    && values.priorities.contains($0.Priority.Priority)
    && values.statuses.contains($0.Status.Status)
}
```

Comment: "If a sequence is empty, `contains(_:)` will just always return false". Does that mean if i filter by user and status but not priority (a non nil field), it will return 0 objects, since every object has a priority value? i would like to NOT filter if its empty. using the code you posted, im still getting unexpected results.

Comment: `!values.categories.isEmpty && values.x.contains($0.Category.Category)` is equivalent to `values.x.contains($0.Category.Category)`. If `values.x` is empty, `values.x.isEmpty` will be `false`, so `!values.x.isEmpty` will be true. Since its empty, `contains(_:)` will always fail to find what you're searching for. `false && false == false`. If the collection has items, then `!values.x.isEmpty` will be `true`, so the `and` expression result is dependant upon `values.x.contains($0.Category.Category)`. In either case, the `isEmpty &&`  make no difference. It's unnecessary.

Comment: ` i would like to NOT filter if its empty` to do this, you would need to add a stipulation to each "predicate". Currently, each predicate permits `$0` to be selected if `values.x` contains `$0.x.x`. What you would like to do is give a free "pass" to every predicate, if `x` is empty. So that's an `or` operation. Either the item is selected because `x` is empty, ***or*** it's selected because `values.x` contains `$0.x.x`. So, each line would be: `(values.x.isEmpty || values.x.contains($0.x.x)) && (values.y.isEmpty || values.y.contains($0.y.y)) && ...`

Comment: wish i can +1 your comments but my account is too new. ill give your examples a try and see if i can get it working as expect. thank you!